# How can I set a route like Instagram? localhost:3000/USERNAME

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I want to set my routes like Instagram (instagram.com/username)

I tried this:

```
router.get('/:name', loggedin, function (req, res, next) {
res.render('profile', {"Request name": req.user});
});
```

But if I visit my /logout route or any other route when I'm logged in it also render the profile Page instead of logging out

Comment: Just add the different routes separately with router.get("route",..) calls. If the only path your routes knows is the /:name wildcard, obviously everything will resolve to that path. If you add stuff like /logout, you will get the behavior you expect

Answer (score 1):

Extend your route by `/logout` to avoid using if statements and make use of POST requests. You generally want most of your user-actions to be POST instead of GET requests.

```
router.post('/:name/logout', loggedin, function (req, res, next) {
  // Logout user here
  // Return data or redirect
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well just use a `if` statement then.

```
router.get('/:name', loggedin, function (req, res, next) {
   if(req.params.name == "logout"){
      //do something...
      return res.json("logged out");
   }
   res.render('profile', {"Request name": req.user});
});
```